# Why can't I link Abel's Step Kick into cl.HP or cl.MP?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

Every time I practice in Training mode, it seems to be a hit and miss.  With the bots set to Auto Block, it seems sometimes I can get very lucky and get it in, but most of the time, it ends up in a block.

I know Counter-Hit makes it easier to link, but since I can't rely solely on Counter-Hits when playing online matches, how am I supposed to nail this down consistently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stepkick into cl.hp is a 1 frame link. If you play on a stick you should try and plink the cl.hp so it becomes a 2 frame link. You cannot combo into cl.mp and also does not make much sense to do so anyway.

Practice it every day on both sides for about 5 to 10 min.

You can also break the combo down.

First do 10x stepkick -> Dash
After you can do it from both sides consistantly put in the cl.hp. After you can do that just add the Change of Direction, etc.

About the counterhit with stepkick:

When you get a counterhit with stepkick, you can also do another stepkick, or go straight for cr.hp. If you cant react fast enough to counterhit, just use cl.hp.

Remember its a 1 frame link, which is not easy. What helps for me is to pay attention to the sound of your dash (the sound from your pad or arcade stick) and use it for timing your cl.hp.

Good luck!

Just a friendly Abel player